# Incompatibility when Managed C++ Wrapper (v110) is consuming Native C++ DLLs (v100)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, c++-cli, wrapper

Thanks in advance...
**Problem:**
Can somebody please help me understand if there is any incompatibility issue when a Wrapper written in C++/CLI (linking to v110, developed in VS2012) is trying to consume native DLL (linking v100, developed in VS2010)?

**Objective:**
I am working on a .net 4.0 application. I am using VS2012 as my dev-environment. This application has to consume some of the legacy C++ Native DLLs. For that I am writing Wrapper project.

**Issue:**
In my wrapper, I am passing a std::vector object reference as a empty-container to be filled by API of my native DLL. This API returns first element perfectly-fine but second element onward, all are dangling-pointers??
Please help me understand what went wrong??

**Alternate solution:**
Everything works fine when I change project setting to link v100 toolset in my Wrapper.

**Questions:**

1. Is v110 and v100 are incompatible to each other in my scenario?
2. There is some other solution available?

Comment: std::vector should not be part of Dll interface. Read compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two *different* std::vector<> implementations.  One from the v100 C++ library, another from the v110 library.  The drastic improvements permitted by the C++11 language revision ensure that they are *not* the same.  Your wrapper will just read garbage when it tries to the access the exported object and/or randomly corrupt it when it writes it.  The CRT has been significantly changed as well, v110 uses a different heap so simple things like allocating an object in one module and destroying it another cannot work either.

Exporting C++ class objects across module boundaries is a perilous adventure, nothing like the execution guarantees you get from a VM like .NET.  Ensuring that all modules are built by the exact same compiler using the exact same settings and a shared copy of the CRT is a hard requirement.